# Get sed extract text between two points, but stop at the second occurrence of a string

Tags: shell, sed

I have a text file with a bunch of power data in it.  I want to extract a section that looks like this:

```
 scan 170110 fission power at tpd 220635.7   total power  107.127

                     Triad3PC-ScanPower v1.1.1.1   ld=2007-03-27

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          burnup type: measbu     lattice split: on     discontinuity factors: normal
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

 34                                               ...                                            34
 33                                   ...     ...     ...     ...                                33
 32                               ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                            32
 31                          ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                        31
 30                      ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                    30
 29                  ...     ...    1.280   1.393   1.232     ...     ...     ...                29
 28                      ...    0.597   1.390     ...   1.289     ...     ...                    28
 27                  ...   0.534    1.113     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                27
 26              ...     ...    1.536     ...     ...   0.706     ...     ...     ...            26
 25          ...     ...   1.207    1.128     ...     ...   0.784     ...     ...     ...        25
 24              ...     ...      ...   0.791   0.831     ...     ...   0.733     ...            24
 23          ...     ...     ...      ...     ...   1.069     ...     ...   1.226     ...        23
 22              ...     ...      ...   0.945   1.204   0.841     ...   0.687     ...            22
 21          ...     ...   1.352      ...   0.826     ...     ...   1.134   1.383     ...        21
 20      ...     ...     ...    2.246     ...   1.639   1.316     ...     ...     ...     ...    20
 19          ...   1.214   0.953    1.551   1.434     ...   1.229   1.048     ...     ...        19
 18      ...     ...   1.256    0.824     ...     ...   1.151   1.132     ...   1.552     ...    18
 17          ...   0.701   1.311      ...   1.796   1.492     ...   2.365   1.101     ...        17
 16      ...     ...     ...      ...     ...     ...     ...   0.970   1.042   1.467     ...    16
 15          ...   1.234     ...    0.863   1.574     ...   1.050   0.923     ...     ...        15
 14      ...     ...     ...      ...     ...   1.642   1.571     ...   1.090   1.473     ...    14
 13          ...     ...   1.062    1.266   1.679   1.599   0.814     ...   1.506     ...        13
 12      ...     ...   1.430      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...    12
 11          ...     ...   0.978      ...   1.342   1.375     ...     ...   1.318     ...        11
 10              ...     ...      ...   0.963     ...   1.066     ...   0.783   0.480            10
  9          ...   1.056     ...    1.291     ...     ...   0.595     ...   0.145     ...         9
  8              ...   1.230      ...     ...   0.760     ...     ...     ...     ...             8
  7          ...     ...   1.313      ...   0.907     ...   0.762   1.534     ...     ...         7
  6              ...     ...    1.306     ...     ...     ...   1.292     ...     ...             6
  5                  ...     ...    1.012   0.818     ...     ...     ...     ...                 5
  4                      ...      ...   1.252     ...   1.299     ...     ...                     4
  3                  ...     ...      ...   1.221   1.145   1.109     ...     ...                 3
  2                      ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                     2
  1                          ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                         1
  0                               ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                             0
 -1                                   ...     ...     ...     ...                                -1
 -2                                               ...                                            -2

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t
```

My sed command is:

```
sed -n  '/fission power at tpd/,/ y   z   a   b   c/ { p; }' s.171012.so.power.info
```

But sed ends up stopping at the first instance of "y   z   a   b   c"

```
     scan 171012 fission power at tpd 239802.1   total power  109.976

                     Triad3PC-ScanPower v1.1.1.1   ld=2007-03-27

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          burnup type: measbu     lattice split: on     discontinuity factors: normal
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t
```

I want it to stop at the second instance at the bottom of the map.  How do I tell it to do that?

Answer (score 3):

#### Using sed

Try:

```
sed -n  '/fission power at tpd/,/ y   z   a   b   c/{/ y   z   a   b   c/!p;}; / y   z   a   b   c/,/ y   z   a   b   c/ { p; }' s.171012.so.power.info
```

To make it easier to read, consider this test file:

```
$ cat file.info
0
begin
1
head
2
3
head
4
```

Our command produces this output:

```
$ sed -n '/begin/,/head/{/head/!p;}; /head/,/head/p' file.info
begin
1
head
2
3
head
```

`/begin/,/head/{/head/!p;}` prints starting with a line containing `begin` up to but not including the first line containing `head`.  `/head/,/head/p` prints from the line containing `head` to the next line containing `head`.

#### Using awk

Since awk understands arithmetic, we can count the number of occurrences of lines containing `head`:

```
$ awk '/begin/{f=1}; f && g<2; f && /head/{g++}' file.info
begin
1
head
2
3
head
```

Like sed, awk processes the input file one line at a time.  Here, we set awk variable `f` to 1 (true) when we reach a line containing `begin`.  If `f` is true and `g` is less than 2 (meaning less than two occurrences of `head`), we print the line.  If `f` is true and the line contains `head`, the we increment `g`.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/fission power at tpd/{:a;N;s/^.*y   z   a   b   c.*/&/M2p;Ta}' file
```

Use the `-n` option to turn off explicit printing i.e. act more like grep.

Gather up lines in the pattern space from a line containing `fission power at tpd` to another line which is the second occurrence of the line containing `y z a b c`.

N.B. The solution uses the substitute command in multi line mode and replaces a line that matches by itself if it occurs twice. The substitution command on success sets an internal flag and if the internal flag is unset, the `T` command transfers program flow to a loop label. Thus the loop will make a collection of lines in the pattern space, print them when a match is made and drop out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

sed is the best tool to use if you're doing s/old/new on individual strings. That's not what you're doing so seds a poor choice to try to use for your application. Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
awk '/fission power at tpd/{f=1} f{print; if ((/y   z   a   b   c/) && (++c == 2)) exit}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to buffer the lines that were read until either the stopping pattern is encountered, in which case they should be outputted, or until end of file is encountered, in which case the buffered lines since the last stopping pattern are discarded. The following solution uses a `~` as a separator between "buffered to be outputted" lines and "buffered but not going to be outputted" lines inside the hold space:

```
start="fission power at tpd"
stop=" y   z   a   b   c"
sed -n '
    # Filter the starting pattern 
    /'"$start"'/,${
        # Add the separator to and hold the line
        s/$/~/; h;
        # foreach line
        :again; n;
            # We hold the line unconditionally, cause its after ~ separator
            H;
            # If its stopping pattern
            /'"$stop"'/{
                # Move the ~ separator to the end of hold buffer
                x;s/~//;s/$/~/;x;
            };
            # If its end of file
            ${
                # output from the hold buffe only the part before ~ separator
                x;s/~.*//;p;q;
            };
            b again;
}' input
```

And a oneliner:

```
sed -n '/'"$start"'/,${ s/$/~/; h; :again; n; H; /'"$stop"'/{x;s/~//;s/$/~/;x;}; ${ x;s/~.*//;p;q; }; b again; }' input
```

You could do it without a separator inside hold space, by acting on pattern buffer as a "lines not to be outputted" buffer. This causes the `stop` pattern not to match the whole line, so one has to remember when writing the pattern not to use `^` anchor, rather `\n` or maybe more along `\(^\|\n\)[^\n]*some_pattern[^\n]*$`.

```
sed -n '
    # Filter from the starting pattern to the of file
    /'"$start"'/,${
        # Hold the starting line and read next line
        h; n;
        # Foreach line
        :again; {
            # If stopping pattern is found
            /'"$stop"'/{
                # Add everything up until now to hold space
                H;
                # Now we could be potentially at end of file here - check it before reading next line
                $!{
                    # Clear pattern space, read next line and restart
                    n;
                    b again;
                }
            };
            # If end of file
            ${
                # print the content of hold space and quit
                x;p;q;
            };
            # Add next line to pattern space
            N;
        }; b again;
}' input
```

And a oneliner:

```
sed -n '/'"$start"'/,${h; n; :again; /'"$stop"'/{ H; $!{ n; b again; }; }; ${ x;p;q; }; N; b again; }' input
```

[Tested on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/StupendousAffectionateSorting#main.sh).